# My english learning is good

Tags: sentence-construction

In the sentence Yesterday the girls send an email. Do you use the word send or sent in the sentence?

I need a answer because I keep getting confused which one to use whenever I use this example to my brother.

Comment: What do you think if the action was in the past?? The present simple in English is mostly for habitual activities and not for ones in the past.

Comment: Please make your question title more relevant to the question

Answer (score 1):

If the sending happened yesterday and you are describing it today, than it happened in the past. You use past tense. "She sent an email." If you were describing it as she did it, then you would use present tense, "She sends an email."

You would never say, "She send an email." The root form is only used in the infinitive, like, "She wants to send an email", or in commands, like "Send an email now!" Maybe some other cases that aren't immediately coming to mind, but NOT as a "plain" "She send an email."